# Runtime variables in Laravel command

Tags: php, laravel

We are currently working on a Laravel API, and we are trying to create commands.
The problem we have been running into is that the command constructor only accepts class objects or a request object. But we'd actually like to pass runtime variables into the command constructor.
We have managed to do this while the development server was running. We were able to pass through arrays and strings to the command. When we tried to restart the development server we ran into the Unresolvable dependency error.

This is the code;

error

```
  Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $data ]] in class App\Console\Commands\SplitFile

  at D:\Users\lphja\Documents\FHICT\Semester 4\GPS\gps_jwplayer_php\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1026
    1022|     protected function unresolvablePrimitive(ReflectionParameter $parameter)
    1023|     {
    1024|         $message = "Unresolvable dependency resolving [$parameter] in class {$parameter->getDeclaringClass()->getName()}";
    1025| 
  > 1026|         throw new BindingResolutionException($message);
    1027|     }
    1028| 
    1029|     /**
    1030|      * Register a new resolving callback.
```

controller

```php
use App\Console\Commands\SplitFile;
use App\Console\Commands\TranslateStrings;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class FileInterpretationController extends Controller
{
    public function translateVtt(Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'filePath' => 'required',
            'targetLanguage' => 'required',
            'fileName' => 'required',
        ]);
        $filePathData = array('filePath' => $validateData['filePath']);
        $splitFile = $this->splitFile($filePathData);
        $data = array(
        'splitFile' => $splitFile,
        'targetLanguage' => $validateData['targetLanguage']
        );
        $translatedSplitVtt = $this->translateStrings($data); //translate string in api logic
        $implodedTranslatedVtt = "WebVTT \n\n";
        foreach ($translatedSplitVtt as $block) {
            $implodedTranslatedVtt .= (gmdate("H:i:s", $block["start"]) . ' ' . '-->' . ' ');
            $implodedTranslatedVtt .= (gmdate("H:i:s", $block["end"]) . "\n");
            $implodedTranslatedVtt .= ('<v ' . $block["voice"] . '>');
            $implodedTranslatedVtt .= ($block["text"]);
            $implodedTranslatedVtt .= ("\n" . "\n");
        }
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $validateData['fileName'] . ".vtt", "wb");
        fwrite($fp, $implodedTranslatedVtt);
        fclose($fp);
        return $implodedTranslatedVtt;
    }

    public function splitFile(array $filePath)
    {
        return ($this->dispatch(new SplitFile($filePath)));
    }
```

command

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\CommandVariables;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Mixed_;
use Podlove\Webvtt\Parser;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SplitFile extends Command
{
    protected $filePath;
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:name';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $data) 
    {
        $this->filePath = $data['filePath'];
        parent::__construct();
     }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $parser = new Parser();
        $content = File::get(storage_path($this->filePath));
        $result = $parser->parse($content);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

We were able to do it while the server was running, but Laravel doesn't seem to want to build.

Comment: Make `SplitFile` a [Job](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#creating-jobs) rather than a command and make a command that can dispatch that job if you need to. There's no reason why you should dispatch a command (nor would I expect it to be possible tbh).  The job itself can accept an array in the parameter, however the command cannot since it will break DI